# How to switch position of two items in a Python list?

Tags: python, list

I haven’t been able to find a good solution for this problem on the net (probably because switch, position, list and Python are all such overloaded words).

It’s rather simple – I have this list:

```
['title', 'email', 'password2', 'password1', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'next', 'newsletter']
```

I’d like to switch position of `'password2'` and `'password1'` – not knowing their exact position, only that they’re right next to one another and `password2` is first.

I’ve accomplished this with some rather long-winded list-subscripting, but I wondered its possible to come up with something a bit more elegant?

Comment: Is your problem the efficiency of trying to find 'password2' in the list?  Can 'password1' come before 'password2'?  Is there some complexity here that doesn't come across in your original question?

Otherwise I agree with @unwind.

Comment: You should post what you've got - I'm curious about what you mean by a "rather long-winded list-subscripting."

Comment: Something along the lines of index1 = index('password1'); index2 = index('password2'); order = order[:index2].append(order[index1]).append(order[index2]).append(order[index1 + 1:]); spread on a few more lines. Pretty, no.

Answer (score 486, accepted):

```
i = ['title', 'email', 'password2', 'password1', 'first_name', 
     'last_name', 'next', 'newsletter']
a, b = i.index('password2'), i.index('password1')
i[b], i[a] = i[a], i[b]
```

Answer (score 218):

The simple Python swap looks like this:

```
foo[i], foo[j] = foo[j], foo[i]
```

Now all you need to do is figure what `i` is, and that can easily be done with `index`:

```
i = foo.index("password2")
```

Answer (score 18):

Given your specs, I'd use slice-assignment:

```
>>> L = ['title', 'email', 'password2', 'password1', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'next', 'newsletter']
>>> i = L.index('password2')
>>> L[i:i+2] = L[i+1:i-1:-1]
>>> L
['title', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'next', 'newsletter']
```

The right-hand side of the slice assignment is a "reversed slice" and could also be spelled:

```
L[i:i+2] = reversed(L[i:i+2])
```

if you find that more readable, as many would.

Comment: Why this is not working if you want to switch title and mail, the first element with the second?

Answer (score 8):

How can it ever be longer than

```
tmp = my_list[indexOfPwd2]
my_list[indexOfPwd2] = my_list[indexOfPwd2 + 1]
my_list[indexOfPwd2 + 1] = tmp
```

That's just a plain swap using temporary storage.

Comment: If you want to be really "Pythonic" about it, you could always do this too: `my_list[indexOfPwd2],my_list[indexOfPwd2+1] = my_list[indexOfPwd2+1],my_list[indexOfPwd2]`

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if l[-1] > l[i]:
        l[-1], l[i] = l[i], l[-1]
        break
```

as a result of this if last element is greater than element at position `i` then they both get swapped .

Answer (score -1):

you can use for example:

```
>>> test_list = ['title', 'email', 'password2', 'password1', 'first_name',
                 'last_name', 'next', 'newsletter']
>>> reorder_func = lambda x: x.insert(x.index('password2'),  x.pop(x.index('password2')+1))
>>> reorder_func(test_list)
>>> test_list
... ['title', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'next', 'newsletter']
```

Answer (score -1):

How to swap every element in a list with the next

```
  for i in range(len(list)):
    try:
      list[i+1]
    except IndexError:
      continue  
    else:
      list[i],list[i+1] = list[i+1],list[i]
```

Comment: This does not swap every element with next. It just pushes first element to the last position.

Answer (score -2):

I am not an expert in python but you could try:
say

```
i = (1,2)

res = lambda i: (i[1],i[0])
print 'res(1, 2) = {0}'.format(res(1, 2))
```

above would give o/p as:

```
res(1, 2) = (2,1)
```

Comment: That does not work without knowing the position of the keys to swap.