# Comb Sorting Program

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am trying to write a program in python which should sort a list within a list.

Examples -

```
List before sorting: [[2, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [3, 1], [1, 1], [1, 2]] 
List after sorting: [[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [2, 2], [3, 1], [3, 3]]

List before sorting: [[3, 3], [2, 2], [1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 1], [1, 1]]
List after sorting: [[1, 1], [2, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 1], [3, 3]]

List before sorting: [[1, 1], [3, 3], [2, 1], [2, 2], [1, 2], [3, 1]]
List after sorting: [[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [2, 2], [3, 1], [3, 3]]
```

My code:

```
import math

def combsort(list1):
    gap = len(list1)
    shrink = 1.3
    sorted = False

    while sorted == False:
        gap = gap/shrink
        if gap > 1:
            sorted = False
        else:
            gap = 1
            sorted = True

        i = 0
        while i + gap < gap:
            distance1 = math.sqrt(list1[i[0]]**2 + list1[i[1]]**2)
            distance2 = math.sqrt(list1[i+gap[0]]**2 + list1[i+gap[1]]**2)
            if distance1 > distance2:
                temporary = list1[i]
                list1[i] = list1[i + gap]
                temporary = list1[i + gap]
                sorted = False
            i = i + 1

list1 = [[2, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [3, 1], [1, 1], [1, 2]] 
combsort(list1)
print(list1)
```

My code doesn't work and prints out the exact same list. Any help?

This is what I was given to follow:

> Comb sort is a variation of bubble sort that generally performs more efficient sorting. It accomplishes this by moving low values near the end of the list further toward the front of the list than bubble sort would during early iterations.
>
> implement a function called combsort that does the following:
>
> 1. Takes as input a 2D list that contains information representing x/y points in 2D space. Each item in the list will be a list with 2
>      items an x and a y coordinate. For example, the list could be [ [0,
>      1],[2, 1], [3, 3], [1, 1], … ]
> 2. List item Performs an in-place sort (i.e., does not create a new list, but modifies the original) using the comb sort algorithm that
>      sorts the 2D list such that points with lower 2 Euclidean distance to
>      the origin (0, 0) appear earlier in the list. In this case, you are
>      comparing distances instead of directly comparing list values – it may
>      be useful to implement and use a distance calculation function. Note –
>      the Euclidean distance of a point (x, y) from the origin (0, 0) can be
>      calculated with the following equation:    distance(x,y) = �! + �!
> 3. Does not return a value. As the input list is sorted in place, it will be modified directly and these modifications will be reflected
>      outside the function, so a return value is not needed.

Comment: Please explain the logic behind your desired order; for example, why does [1,2] sometimes come before [2,1] but not always?

Comment: @ScottHunter I thought this was a typo, but it is indeed correct. Since the distance is how they're sorted, `[1,2]` and `[2,1]` are equivalent values, and thus their order depends on initial position.

Comment: If `i` is any integer value greater than `-1`, the code inside the `while i + gap < gap:` loop can never execute.

Comment: @River: Although the clarity of my feelings to you isn't important, I did it to specify the reason in more mathematical terms.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop never gets executed because its condition cannot be true:

```
while i + gap < gap:
```

Hint: use more print statements or a debugger to check the values of things while the program is running.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your `while` statement, it should be:

```
while i + gap < len(list1):
```

as shown in the [pseudocode here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_sort#Pseudocode). Currently the `while` loop is never even entered... which hides your other problems (see below).

You are indexing into a 2-D list wrong:

```
list1[i[0]] #get first item in list `i` and use that number to index into list1
list1[i][0] #get the ith sublist in list1 and get its first item
```

You need to make sure you use integers for your list indices:

```
gap = int(gap/shrink)
```

And for the grand finale....you swapped the order of your assignment, ruining your swap logic

```
temporary = list1[i + gap] #wrong
list1[i + gap] = temporary #should be this
```

You can also do this [without the use of `temporary` in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493920/how-to-switch-position-of-two-items-in-a-python-list):

```
list1[i+gap], list1[i] = list1[i], list1[i+gap]
```

After all these changes, the code works as expected:

```
>>>combsort([[3, 3], [2, 2], [1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 1], [1, 1]])
[[1, 1], [2, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 1], [3, 3]]
```

Comment: I've done everything. Except I don't understanding the indexing into a 2-d list part? Can you please explain that part more?

Comment: If you have 2D list, it is just like any other list. Take `list1` as an example. If we want the first item, we say `x = list1[0]`, just as with a 1D list. However in this case, `x` is *itself* a list. If we want the first item in that, we do the same as with `list1` and say `y = x[0]`. Subbing `list1[0]` for `x` (they are the same after all), gets us `y = list1[0][0]`, or "`y` is the first item in the first item of `list1`". Note that this assumes the first item of `list1` is also a list.

Comment: Now look at what it would mean if we do what you did with `list1[i[0]]`. The innermost item you have is `i[0]`. This means "get the first item of list `i`". But `i` is not a list so this will error. If `i` *were* a list, then `list1[i[0]]` would mean "Use this first item of `i` to index into `list1`". E.g. if `i = [2,3,4]`, `i[0] = 2` and so `list1[i[0]]` is `list1[2]`, or the third item of `list1`. Note that this assumes `i[0]` is an integer, otherwise it can't be used to index into a list, and will also give you an error.

Comment: I separated them. Still not working? I get an error code on the distance2. 

            distance1 = math.sqrt(list1[i][0]**2 + list1[i][1]**2)
            distance2 = math.sqrt(list1[i]+gap[0]**2 + list1[i]+gap[1]**2)

Comment: @User9123 You want `list1[i+gap][0]` (and similar for second part). `gap` is not a list as `gap[0]` assumes, so that's why you get the error.

Comment: @User9123 also if this post solved your problem, you can accept it using the check mark next to it