# conversion from if statements to efficient for loop based solution for INSERTION SORT in Python

Tags: python, sorting, if-statement, insertion

I have the following code that performs an insertion sort for 4 items in a list. It works, but it uses IF statements. I am interested in the various solutions that show a)conversion (based on my code and variables) to a simpler more efficient algorithm using loops where there is repetition and b) a clear explanation as to where/why what has been implemented.

The code for the insertion sort using IF statements:

```
def main():
  list=[4,1,2,6]
  print("original list:",list)
  cv=list[1]
  if cv<list[0]:
    list[1]=list[0]
    list[0]=cv
    print("Compare element 1 with 0:",list)

  cv=list[2]
  if cv<list[1]:
    list[2]=list[1]
    list[1]=cv
    print("Compare element 2 with 1 & shift 1 upto 2:",list)
    if cv<list[0]:
      list[1]=list[0]
      list[0]=cv
      print("Compare element 2 with 0 and shift 0 and 1 up:",list)

  cv=list[3]
  if cv<list[2]:
    list[3]=list[2]
    list[2]=cv
    print("Compare element 3 with 2 & shift 2 upto 3:",list)
    if cv<list[1]:
      list[2]=list[1]
      list[1]=cv
      print("Compare element 3 with 1 and shift 1 and 2 up:",list) 
      if cv<list[0]:
        list[1]=list[0]
        list[0]=cv
        print("Compare element 3 with 0 and shift 0 up:",list)

main()
```

How does *this code above* translate into a **for loop/loop based solution** + I'd also be interested in a **recursive** solution, but again derived directly from this one for teaching/learning purposes.

One could start, for example, by reocgnising that each iteration is done for lengthoflist-1 times.

**So:**

```
 for i in range((len(list))-1):
    cv=list[i+1]
    etc
```

I get that there will be an outer loop and an inner loop. How are these best constructed, and again, a clear explanation as to how the solution is derived from this original if-based code, is what I'm after.

Comment: I searched for `[python] insertion sort` and found several examples.

Comment: Blurp..so did I but I am asking for something specific. Conversion of this specific code into a simplified solution using loops

Comment: I'm not sure it makes sense to convert your specific code to a loop-based version. Regardless, you should make an attempt and see what you come up with first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, *never* name a list `"list"` as it overrides the built-in `list()` function. Instead, I have named it `l`:

```
l = [4, 1, 2, 6]
```

Then, we need to simply do a `for-loop` that loops over the indexes in `l`. We need to start at index `1` though (second element) as `insertion` works by shifting elements *left* (as you know) and so we should start at the second element and go to the last (so the length of `l`: `len(l)`).

Then we want to begin a `while` `loop`. This will continue whilst the current element at `i` (the `index`) in the `list` is smaller than the element to its *left* and `i` is greater than `0` (so we haven't gone off the end).

For example, in the first iteration of the `for-loop`, `i` will be `1` which has the element value of `1` in `l`. As `1` is greater than `l[i-1]` (this is `4`) and `i` which is `1` is `> 0` which it is, we enter the `while`.

In the `while` `loop`, all we do is switch the current element and the one to its left with the nice syntax [stolen from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493920/how-to-switch-position-of-two-items-in-a-python-list).

Finally, the last thing to do in the `while` is to decrease the index by `1` i.e. move the current position to the left so we can then to another switch if it is yet again smaller than the element to its left.

So after all that explanation, here is the code:

```
for i in range(1, len(l)):
    while l[i] < l[i-1] and i > 0:
        l[i-1], l[i] = l[i], l[i-1]
        i -= 1
```

which modifies `l` to:

```
[1, 2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: Whoever down voted, sorry I had missed a vital step of the algorithm which I have added now.

Comment: Thanks...I certainly didn't downvote. Will have a look in a mo

Comment: I will check if your solution works but what I'm after mainly is how to SIMPLIFY the exact code I've posted into a solution using loops. The aim is to identify which ifs and index numbers etc easily lend themselves to conversion into a loop ...... thanks in advance

Comment: @MissComputing I tried to make it clear in the explanation, but this *is* the exact same idea as in your long code. What has changed is that instead of having `3` blocks of `if-statements`, we now have a `for-loop` that will run `3` times and instead of having `1`, `2` or `3` `if-statements` trying to shift the element to the *left*, we just use a `while-loop`. This is literally the same code, just neatened up!

Comment: Thank you Joe - don't worry if not, as I've accepted the answer, but I wondered a) is it possible to solve this with a nested for, rather than with a while? b) What about a recursive solution, would this be even more elegant? (again both based on simplifying my original code). Thanks again!

Comment: @MissComputing I'll have a look tommorow, using a nested for is definitely possible. Using a recursive function would be possible (all loops can be written recursively) but I don't think it it would be any more elegant. Nevertheless, I will see tomorrow :)