# I am trying to swap the two elements in the list, but after the first swap it keeps getting swapped as it fits the condition to be swapped

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write in python a list num having the following elements:  num = [3 ,21 ,5 ,6 ,14 ,8 ,14 ,3] . Write a program to swap the content with the next value divisible by 7 so that the resultant list looks like:  num = [3, 5, 21, 6, 8, 14, 3, 14]

This one is my code...

```
num = [3, 21, 5, 6, 14, 8, 14, 3]
for i in range(len(num)-1):
    if num[i] % 7 == 0:
        num[i + 1], num[i] = num[i], num[i + 1]
print(num)
```

output...

[3, 5, 6, 14, 8, 14, 3, 21]

After the first swap, the if statement checks 21 again and again, and it gets pushed to the end of the list in contrast with the desired output. I have to check other elements too that are divisible by 7 and swap them with the succeeding element.
Can I skip one iteration after each swap?

Comment: so what have you tried?

Comment: Please don't ask for full code. Show your attempt and take help when you get stuck in a certain place.

Comment: @ChristianSloper Anyway, it's a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493920/how-to-switch-position-of-two-items-in-a-python-list ....

Comment: Use a debugger to step through your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
num = [3, 21, 5, 6, 14, 8, 14, 3]
num.reverse()
for i in range(len(num)-1):
    if num[i] % 7 == 0:
        num[i - 1], num[i] = num[i], num[i - 1]
num.reverse()
print("The required answer :", num)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can swap values by just assigning their values like this:

```
a, b = b, a
```

You can easily do this exercise with a for loop, checking every time if the next number is divisible by 7, and if so, swap them using this code

Comment: This is not the answer to the problem.

Comment: @MayankPorwal why? It doesn't show exactly how to use it, but that's basically the asnwer...

Comment: This seems more like a suggestion/comment rather than an answer. When you answer someone's post, in my opinion at least solve the problem completely. Don't just give suggestions. Comments are there for such things.

Comment: If I do this kind of swap, it shows an index error.

Comment: In this line...        num[i + 1], num[i] = num[i], num[i + 1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: In the for loop, you have to iterate until the n-1 element, to prevent this error

Comment: Thanks, but still i am not getting my desired output. it pushes 21 to the end of the the list like this [3, 5, 6, 14, 8, 14, 3, 21]. I understand why this happens. Can I skip one iteration of the for loop just after swaping?

Comment: Thanks guys, but I traversed the list in reverse and got my results, suggested by one of of my classmate